# Wordpress catch first image with youtube

Tags: php, wordpress

I am attempting to add some functionality to a wordpress site that does the following...

- Checks post for either the first image or the first youtube embed
- If it finds an image first then return it
- If it finds a youtube embed first then return a screenshot

I have found a couple of similar examples on line but nothing that fits the bill, heres what I am using so far...

```
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content,     $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

This works correctly and returns the first image of the post correctly, I am now struggling to add the youtube funcitonality,  I have found the following snippet of code online but I am not sure how to add it on to the function above..

```
preg_match( '#https?://www\.youtube(?:\-nocookie)?\.com/embed/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)#', $markup, $matches );
    }

    // If we've found a YouTube video ID, create the thumbnail URL
    if ( isset( $matches[1] ) ) {
        $youtube_thumbnail = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $matches[1] . '/0.jpg';
    }
```

The logic for picking a youtube video thumb over an image if there are both in a post can come later, for now I only have posts with either images or a youtube embed.  Can anyone help combine the two?

---

****EDIT****

After using hakres excellent example and answer I am using this...

```
function catch_image($content, $defaultImage = '/images/default.jpg')
{
    $image = $defaultImage;
    $found = strlen($content);
    foreach (array(
                 'image'   => array(
                     'regex' => '/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i',
                     'mask'  => '%s'
                 ),
                 'youtube' => array(
                     'regex' => '#(?:https?(?:a|vh?)?://)?(?:www\.)?    youtube(?:\-nocookie)?\.com/watch\?.*v=([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)#',
                     'mask'  => 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/%s/2.jpg'
                 ),
             ) as $search)
    {
        extract($search);
        if (preg_match($regex, $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)
            && $matches[1][1] < $found
        ) {
            list($image, $found) = $matches[1];
            $image = sprintf($mask, $image);
        }
    }
    return $image;
}
```

I have modified the youtube regex statement slightly and also the mask for displaying the image and everything is working.

However I now need to try and add these as well....

```
'regex' => '#<object[^>]+>.+?https?://www\.youtube(?:\-nocookie)?\.com/[ve]/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+).+?</object>#s',
'regex' => '#https?://www\.youtube(?:\-nocookie)?\.com/[ve]/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)#',
'regex' => '#https?://www\.youtube(?:\-nocookie)?\.com/embed/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)#',
'regex' => '#(?:https?(?:a|vh?)?://)?(?:www\.)?youtube(?:\-nocookie)?\.com/watch\?.*v=([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)#',
'regex' => '#(?:https?(?:a|vh?)?://)?youtu\.be/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)#',
```

This would then cover all the different ways a youtube video could be embedded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here some pointers to solve your problem:

1. You do multiple tests, one for the first image, one for the youtube video.
2. Both tests can be successfull or not.
3. The one test which comes first (in position) should win.

Both tests you do are based on a regular expressions. You look for a pattern and if matched, your pick out a match. For the image, the image src, for the youtube video, the video-id which needs to be put into a string then. So you do a matching, pick one match if right and integrate that into a pattern. So actually both things are the same, only the pattern and the mask vary. Example:

```
array(
     'image'   => array(
         'regex' => '/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i',
         'mask'  => '%s'
     ),
     'youtube' => array(
         'regex' => '#https?://www\.youtube(?:\-nocookie)?\.com/embed/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)#',
         'mask'  => 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/%s0.jpg'
     ),
 );
```

So if you initialize the finding to the default image at the end of the string, and then look for any further searches and check if they match where they have matched. And if they matched before the last match, they win and the match will be updated:

```
/**
 * Representa! - Pimp ur posts media
 *
 * @author   hakre <http://hakre.wordpress.com>
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @param string $defaultImage (optional)
 *
 * @return string
 */
function representa_image($content, $defaultImage = '/images/default.jpg')
{
    $image = $defaultImage;
    $found = strlen($content);
    foreach (array(
                 'image'   => array(
                     'regex' => '/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i',
                     'mask'  => '%s'
                 ),
                 'youtube' => array(
                     'regex' => '#https?://www\.youtube(?:\-nocookie)?\.com/embed/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)#',
                     'mask'  => 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/%s0.jpg'
                 ),
             ) as $search)
    {
        extract($search);
        if (preg_match($regex, $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)
            && $matches[1][1] < $found
        ) {
            list($image, $found) = $matches[1];
            $image = sprintf($mask, $image);
        }
    }
    return $image;
}
```

Usage:

```
$url = representa_image($post->post_content);
```

I hope this has simplified your issue and gives you some idea how such problem(s) can be solved. Take note that I'm using `preg_match` and the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag which will return the position where matched with each match.

Comment: That's amazing, it really has explained it in a simple way I can get my head round!  I have modified it ever so slightly and applied it and it is working correctly.  I have updated my original post with another question regarding the different ways of searching for youtube videos

Comment: @fightstarr20: You could either try to create one youtube regex out of it or you just add more to the array, e.g. `youtube2`, `youtube3` etc..

Answer (score 1):

Okay i implement this code for filmyboss.com which can search if video of that keyword is already in db then it show search result else it search in youtube with that keyword and update it i think you can debug it easily with your needs

```
 global $query_string;

                        if(have_posts()):
    //You already have it 
    else:
    $x = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=some&format=5&max-results=1&v=2&duration=long&alt=jsonc"));
                        $y = $x->data;
                        $z = $y->items;
                        $d['_my_meta']['ytkey'] = $z['0']->id;
                        $t = $z['0']->title;
                        $post = array(
                        'post_status' => 'publish', 
                        'post_title' => $t, //The title of your post.
                        'post_type' => 'post');
                        echo $d; 
                        $key = "_my_meta";
                        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );
    endif;
```

Comment: Its order by size means 0.jpg is smallest and 3.jpg is largest so you can decide according to size you want

Comment: I understand what your saying, but it doesn't seem to be related to my question!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but I really don't understand what your getting at.  I have updated my original question above with where I am at so far